# Running selenium scripts on remote machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, eclipse

I have created some selenium scripts for one of the websites of my client. The scripts are in my local machine, running successfully. I want show a demo to my Project Manager on his personal laptop(he does not want to install selenium on his personal computer). I developed scripts using selenium webdriver + maven + Eclipse.

Comment: will remotely accessing your PC from your PM's desktop solve your problem? BTW this solution is not related to Selenium in any way.

Comment: Can you simply do a screenshare on google hangouts? this would show him the work you have done without getting all the selenium products onto his machine.

Comment: @Peter Masiar , Its not the case of accessing my PC from Remotely .I want to know how can I know execute these test cases in his PC.So that he can give a demo to client whenever he required with out of my presence.

Comment: If you want to run Selenium locally, obviously you have to install it, right? How your manager want to run locally program which is not installed?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you are using a test framework like testng on spock, if you are then plugging it into a remote jenkins and show the status in jenkins should be your standard approach. If trust is an issue you can have selenium take screen shots at key points along the way (or even in the afterMethod method). One thing we ran into with jenkins though is selnium does not run well when it runs in the background (as a service)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jenkins (CI) there is a sweet Selenium plugin that you can run test on 'slaves'. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzAnUzqAsqE) of the author of both giving a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use selenium grid

[Selenium Grid Documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)

[Setting up Grid](http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html)

Your Machine == Hub

PM's machine == Node

Answer (score 0):

Project managers and client should be more worried about the result of the tests then running the actual tests. In order to get an impression, maybe you can record the tests and they can play back the video. The build-server running the tests could even record the full test run if you want, services like SauceLabs have these videos available by default.

If a recording is not enough there is only one solution: Install Selenium, Java and Maven. If you run the tests from the command-line Eclipse should not be needed, but you do need the application hosted somewhere with the correct version. Also you will need to put the test source in version control so the runner can collect the newest tests.

I would suggest you setup a build server which runs the tests and records the video. Anyone can then view the results of the tests on a central location and can if wanted see the video of the whole test run.

Personally I would be more impressed when a supplier has the whole build chain automated and can download test results from a recent build, then when a project manager runs some tests on his local laptop and doesn't know what todo when it stops working, because he is not technical enough. :)

Comment: Hello @Niels,Thanks for your answer.I have not understood the concept of "build server".Can you please elaborate this or could please share some url's

Comment: Is build server is   nothing but a CI(ex:Jenkins) etc .. ??

Comment: Yes, something like Jenkins runs the tests and stores the results. Now anyone can login to Jenkins to start a test run and show the results to who needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can install vm ware horizon client and install eclipse .
You can execute all your testcase in your vm ware eclipse .To give demo you can install vmware in your manager's laptop and login with ur vmware id and password .Hope this ll help you .